# extract a file from a set of tgz files

Tags: unix, tar

I have a set of tgz files and want to extract a particular file from each tgz file.
Is there a one line command for same or should it be done in a loop.
I tried this but it extracted only file from a single folder.

tar -zxvf *.tgz --wildcards '*copo*'

Answer (score 0):

try below command -

Consider you have two tgz files -

```
vipin@kali:~$ ls -ltr *tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 171 Nov  6 03:56 combine.tar.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 159 Nov  6 03:56 combine1.tar.tgz
```

And both of them contain a file 3.txt

```
vipin@kali:~$ zcat *tgz
1.txt0000644000175000017500000000001613007570074011013 0ustar  vipinvipintesting file2
2.txt0000644000175000017500000000001613007570074011014 0ustar  vipinvipintesting file2
3.txt0000644000175000017500000000001613007570074011015 0ustar  vipinvipintesting file2
4.txt0000644000175000017500000000001613007570074011016 0ustar  vipinvipintesting file2
1.txt0000644000175000017500000000002613007570022011005 0ustar  vipinvipintesting
testing file1
2.txt0000644000175000017500000000002613007570022011006 0ustar  vipinvipintesting
testing file1
**3.txt0000644000175000017500000000002613007570022011007 0ustar  vipinvipintesting**
testing file1
4.txt0000644000175000017500000000002613007570022011010 0ustar  vipinvipintesting
testing file1
5.txt0000644000175000017500000000002613007570022011011 0ustar  vipinvipintesting
testing file1
```

And you need 3.txt from both tgz files.

```
vipin@kali:~$ for i in *tar.tgz;do tar -xf $i 3.txt && mv 3.txt $i.3.txt;done
vipin@kali:~$ ls -ltr combine*txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 22 Nov  6 03:55 combine.tar.tgz.3.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 14 Nov  6 03:56 combine1.tar.tgz.3.txt
```